# Protractor: check the border-radius using getCssValue

Tags: css, protractor

I'm new to protractor and I want to check some css properties. I'm doing it like this (CoffeeScript):

```
element.all(By.css(".my-picture")).then (pictures) ->
   for picture in pictures
      picture.getCssValue("border-radius").then (value) ->
         console.log value
```

The above code does not print anything. I can get properties like "display" or "color", but no "border-radius".

According to [this documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue(java.lang.String)), it seems that `getCssValue` just works with CSS2 specification. And according to [CSS2Properties doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSS2Properties), `border-radius` does not exists!

Now, I realize that `border-radius` is a CSS3 property. But the question remains, how can I test it using protractor?

Comment: Can getAttribute help in this!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element.all(by.css('.my-picture')).then(function (pictures) {
    for (picture in pictures) {
        browser.executeScript(function (domPicture) {
            var style = window.getComputedStyle(domPicture);
            return style.getPropertyValue('border-radius');
        }, picture.getWebElement()).then(function (borderRadius) {
            console.log(borderRadius);
        });
    }
});
```